# Programatically detect system sleep and wakeup event in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, suspend, wakeup, events

I wanted to detect and get notified on the events when the system is about to sleep and when the system has been just awake from sleep in my application. On platform like mac, the system receives these event in some handler after we register for these events. Is there some similar way to be notified of these event in the application at runtime for both sleep and wake system events in ubuntu?